# Jquery added class rule executes on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I am using jquery validate to validate a form and adding a class rule using

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("checkDuplicate", {checkDuplicate: true});
});
```

The function checkDuplidate executes an ajax call to check some value if exists in database and returns response accordingly. The issue I am facing is when I use this for a blank form it works fine but when I am editing the form i.e. value is prefilled on page load the class rule gets executed.
I think the issue is related with the document.ready but I am not able to figure out the place to put this code to stop its execution on page load.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you don't want to perform validation on page load if the field is pre-filled?

Comment: @Terry - Yes I only want it on focusout or on submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the validation on form submit?

```js
$(document).on('submit','#formId',function(){
   jQuery.validator.addClassRules("checkDuplicate", {checkDuplicate: true});
});
```

Replace "#formId" with the formId you are using in your html.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I also want to add the validation on focusout so I added the same validation rule on focusout also. Solved my issue.